# Put image in Sort Order MVC WebGrid

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to put a background image in the column when you sort the WebGrid

the code I have in the VIew is the following:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    fillEmptyRows: true,
    headerStyle: "hearder-grid",
    ... 
             )
```

code in the Css Style:

```
tr.hearder-grid .asc{
                background: transparent url('/Content/themes/base/Images/asc.png') center right no-repeat;

        }

tr.hearder-grid .desc{
                background: transparent url('/Content/themes/base/Images/desc.png') center right no-repeat;
        }
```

this code does not work

someone can help me?

blessings

Answer (score 0):

You need a Helper.

```
   public static class SortHelper
     {
       public static MvcHtmlString Direction(this HtmlHelper helper, string columnName)
         {
           string html = "";
           if (columnName.Contains("whatever name you are using to represent descending"))
            {
               html = "▲";
            }
          else
           {
             html = "▼";
           }
           return MvcHtmlString.Create(html);
        }
   }
```

Then you just concatenate with the header

```
 SortDirectionHelper.SortDirection(null, "columnname")
```

You can see a better example in the following url:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4SoNOwbKek